# Popup with scrollable area

Tags: libgdx

In my game, I planned to use show the IAP items in a pop up. The pop up area should be scrollable so that I can show the next items.

I am new to the scroll feature available in LibGdx. Could you please point me the right tutorial / Sample ?

Just a note - I have developed the game without using Scen2D.